# Retrieve S3 file as Object instead of downloading to absolute system path

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I just started learning and using S3, read the docs. Actually I didn't find anything to fetch the file into an object instead of downloading it from S3? if this could be possible, or I am missing something?

Actually I want to avoid additional IO after downloading the file.

Comment: Does  GetObject (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html ) help?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use `StringIO` and get file content from S3 using `get_contents_as_string`, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

AWS_KEY = 'XXXXXXDDDDDD'
AWS_SECRET = 'pweqory83743rywiuedq'
aws_connection = S3Connection(AWS_KEY, AWS_SECRET)
bucket = aws_connection.get_bucket('YOUR_BUCKET')

fileName = "test.csv"

content = bucket.get_key(fileName).get_contents_as_string()
reader = pd.read_csv(StringIO.StringIO(content))
```

Answer (score 82):

You might be looking for the `get_object()` method of the boto3 S3 client:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object

This will get you a response object dictionary with member `Body` that is a  `StreamingBody` object, which you can use as normal file and call `.read()` method on it. To get the entire content of the S3 object into memory you would do something like this:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
s3_response_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME_STRING, Key=FILE_NAME_STRING)
object_content = s3_response_object['Body'].read()
```

Comment: Can you tell us how we can save this in local machine? 
I wanted to get mime of the file, for that I have to save it.

Comment: For saving to local machine there's a different S3 API `download_file`. The file can get saved to any absolute path you specify.

Answer (score 32):

I prefer this approach, equivalent to [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37137634/39396):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def read_s3_contents(bucket_name, key):
    response = s3.Object(bucket_name, key).get()
    return response['Body'].read()
```

But another approach could read the object into `StringIO`:

```
import StringIO
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
def read_s3_contents_with_download(bucket_name, key):
    string_io = StringIO.StringIO()
    s3.Object(bucket_name, key).download_fileobj(string_io)
    return string_io.getvalue()
```

Comment: What is `return` here? Is this a function? Can you please post the whole working example?

Comment: Hi @Joe, I was using the `return` keyword here loosely to indicate the thing that a programmer wants.  I wrapped the statements in function definitions to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks. How would you read PARQUET file from S3 into variable `string_io`? I tried above code and getting error: `TypeError: string argument expected, got 'bytes'`.

Comment: Hi @Joe, Python 3 has `BytesIO` you can try using instead of `StringIO`.  If that doens't help, you might need to ask a new question.

Comment: @Joe I have a solution to that problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55732615/how-do-i-read-a-gzipped-parquet-file-from-s3-into-python-using-boto3/55732616 using the tip of `BytesIO` suggested by @Carl G