# tempfile.TemporaryFile seems empty even though it's not

Tags: python, temporary-files

I am writing to a temporary file by downloading the file from S3. When I open the downloaded file (called `3`) in my text editor, I can see all the lines of text. But my code returns nothing when I try to read the file line by line.

After running the code, the temporary file is created in the directory of the Python script and doesn't disappear.

```
import tempfile
import os

import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tf:
  try:
    s3.download_file(
      Bucket='the-chumiest-bucket',
      Key='path/to/the/file.txt',
      Filename=str(tf.name)
    )
  except Exception as e:
    print('error:', e)

  tf.flush()
  tf.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)

  for line in tf.readlines():
    print('line:', line)
```

If I run

```
with open('3', 'r') as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
    print(line)
```

I get the lines, so this could be a workaround, but I've seen many people read lines from a tempfile using this exact method.

#### Expected Result:

I get the lines within `file.txt` printed.

#### Actual Result:

I get nothing printed.

### Edit #1

Changed `tf.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)` to `tf.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)` (thanks @Barmar) and still no lines being printed. Just one blank line.

Comment: You're using `SEEK_END` to seek to the end of the file. There's no data to read after that point.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696472/seek-function

Comment: Maybe instead of downloading to a file, you should just download directly to an object. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087203/retrieve-s3-file-as-object-instead-of-downloading-to-absolute-system-path

Comment: Try using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` because what `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` returns isn't a real file (only a "file-like" object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeking to the end of the file. There's nothing more to read when you're at the end. You should see to the beginning.

```
tf.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
```

I suspect the other problem is that you're updating the file outside of the `tf` stream. It's not going back to the filesystem to read the file contents. `tf.flush()` flushes the output buffer, but that doesn't do anything since you haven't written to the stream.

Instead of seeking in the `tf` stream, reopen the file:

```
with open(tf.name) as tf1:
  for line in tf1.readlines():
    print('line:', line)
```

Note that you should be using `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` to get a file that's named. And reopening the file only works on Unix, not Windows. You might want to use `tempfile.mkstemp()` instead, as I don't think it has that OS-dependency.

Comment: not sure if I can do this in my Serverless environment, I'll try it now. thanks.

Comment: If `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` is used, it _can_ be reopened if a  `delete=False` is use to create it…but of course that would also imply that it would have to be explicitly deleted when it's no longer needed.